# Validation model in Ruby/Sinatra API

Tags: ruby, validation, rest, sinatra

I'm building the REST API of a platform I'm working on in Ruby, on top of Sinatra.

Data comes in during a POST, at that stage, I check the format of parsed JSON against a validation hash built for each route with hash_validator.

The POST data, if valid, is passed into as a single hash to create a new class (e.g. User). So at the initialization, I check each variable to make sure they exist and are not nil.

Parts of the same object can reside in various collections (UserInfo, UserSubscriptions, UserPasswordHash etc.), so when loading the class from data store, I again validate each hash received through (in my case, Mongo).

This works so far but with a lot of repetitions of variable names around the code and it may still not be data-proof.

I'm following my engineering guts as much as possible on this but is there a common model to follow when validating input at various stages in the app?

Answer (score 0):

You never need to check your validations when loading data from the database. If you validate on the way in you can assume it's valid coming out. I would perform validations on the way in in one step.  Initialize your object with the data passed and check to make sure various attributes are valid. If the data being posted isn't valid the attributes will fail validation

Comment: How about to inform API users about missing data? User.photo.url may be missing inside the class but how do you tell the user that the cause of the problem is they did not include { user: { photo: { url: } } } }

Comment: Are you using nested attributes to pass back that data? Rails should take care of that for you

Comment: it's a Ruby/Sinatra app, not using Rails.

Comment: My fault, what ORM are you using? Activerecord comes with build in support for nested attributes and I would imagine datamapper has something you can use for this scenario as well